# After the grace period is over, the bounty indicator still shows, only that it then does not allow awarding it

Tags: bug, bounties, expired-bounty

I possibly hit a race condition between the end of the grace period of a bounty and the time the notice is automatically removed.

On Aug 7, 5.08 (everything in UTC in this post) I started a bounty to a question (see [revisions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/25982/revisions) or [timeline](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/25982/timeline)). After seven days it ended and entered in the grace period. By Aug 15, 00.01 I received an email from Stack Overflow:

> Your bounty on the question … [Paso de B a U: ¿evolución fonética o falta de ortografía?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25982/1674) … ended and will be auto-closed after the 24-hour grace period expires.

When I woke up I opened the link on my mobile by around 7 am. The bounty indicator was still next to the unique answer, so I clicked on it. However, it showed a message saying more or less "there is no bounty". Surprised by it, I refreshed the page and found out that the bounty indicator next to the answer was gone. Only later I realized that the grace period was over, so it was correct that I couldn't award anymore.

In any case:

- The email about the grace period was sent at 00.01, which seems to be the standard for bounties (I checked other cases).
- The timeline shows *Bounty Ended with no winning answer by Community♦* at Aug 15, 7.02, which is 2 hours after the grace period was over.
- The visual indicator to allow awarding a bounty was still there even after the bounty was over. I cannot recall if the notice below the question was still there.